# MPIEXEC wrapper

Tags: c++, command-prompt, mpich

I use MPIEXEC wrapper program to execute my programs in MPICH2. After my program performed its task **Break** button doesn't become passive, similarly **Execute** button doesn't become active. Though my program reaches to the end, I have to press **Break** button. If I run my program directly by mpiexec command in the *Windows Command Prompt*, everything is ending normally.

If I don't press Break button, and If I press Ctrl+C (for example for a copy/paste process), then the MPIEXEC wrapper displays a warning *"unable to forward stdin, send failed, error 10054, An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."* at the end of line.

What is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are those buttons? In your IDE?

Comment: They are in the program named as MPIEXEC wrapper (provided by MPICH2 Windows version). Its file name is wmpiexec.exe. This IDE is used for simplifying mpiexec command.